# What is the best way to access controller variables within Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

## Controller

In my controller, I have an array store in this variable `$month_g`

```
dd($month_g);
```

I got

```
array:12 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "up_bytes" => 277664452
    "down_bytes" => 198868462
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "up_bytes" => 0
    "down_bytes" => 0
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▶]
  3 => array:2 [▶]
  4 => array:2 [▶]
  5 => array:2 [▶]
  6 => array:2 [▶]
  7 => array:2 [▶]
  8 => array:2 [▶]
  9 => array:2 [▶]
  10 => array:2 [▶]
  11 => array:2 [▶]
]

return view('page.index', get_defined_vars());
```

I want to be able to access this variable in my JS/View.

---

## View

index.blade.php

**I've tried**

```
@extends('layouts.internal.master')
@section('content')

..... // content in HTML

@stop

@section('pagescripts')
    <script>
        console.log('{{$month_g}}');
    </script> 
@stop
```

---

## Result

I kept getting

> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

But **console.log()** is capable of printing out an array.

---

## Questions

How do I `console.log` that out ? What did I miss here ?

What is the best way to access controller variables within Javascript ?

Comment: You could JSON encode the array inside the view and JSON decode it in JS

Comment: Admittedly, I'm not too familiar w/ Laravel/Blade templates, but I imagine `'{{$month_g}}'` is trying to convert your array to a string. That's where you'd need to encode it.

Comment: @Whymarrh : I'll try that. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$month_g` is a PHP array, you want to first convert it to JSON so that javascript can use it.

```
<script>
var month_g = <?php echo json_encode($month_g) ?>;

console.log(month_g);
</script>
```

PHP's `json_encode` method is the safest way to output PHP variables to be javascript variables in general. Even if you think the variable is an integer or simple string, `json_encode` it anyway just to be safe.

Side note, you can also use Laravel's way instead of PHP tags if you prefer. Just note you need to use `{!!` instead of `{{` so that the output isn't escaped.

```
<script>
var month_g = {!! json_encode($month_g) !!};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try json_encode()

```
 return view('page.index', ['month_g' => json_encode($month_g)];
```

and from your view

```
@section('pagescripts')
<script>
    console.log('{!! $month_g !!}');
</script> 
@stop
```